# PHP string compare: odd result, possible type juggling, no idea why

Tags: php, type-conversion, operator-keyword

I'm aware that numeric strings may be type juggled in PHP, but I can't see why it's happening here or giving this result:

```
$a="00010010001101000000101";
$b="00010010001101000000001";

$c = (($a == $b) ? "true" : "false");
$d = (($a === $b) ? "true" : "false");

echo $c . "  " . $d . "\n";  // true false
```

But in this case $a and $b are defined the same way, of the same length, but different contents many chars in. How is ($a == $b) evaluating as true?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  I'm getting `false false`.

Comment: Also getting `false false` on 5.4.16

Comment: Seems to be a known bug, which is fixed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547

Can confirm at least PHP 5.4.17 not affected anymore.

Comment: @Scuzzy  You're using php 5.4> and he's using php 5.3 or lower!

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com you can try it in various php verions to see which work and which dont

Comment: Was fixed in 5.4.4: http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.4 (it's bug #54547 "wrong equality of string numbers" as ukautz already said).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug. Test it on http://3v4l.org/CMld0 .

Version `4.3.1 - 5.0.5` and `5.1.1 - 5.4.3` return `true false`.

Versions `5.4.4 - 5.5.3` return `false false`.

Comment: ofc there is https://bugs.php.net/ . But no need to report this bug, since it is already fixed >=5.4.4